# Debian 9.X issues with VMWare workstation

Tags: linux, debian, virtual-machine, vmware

I don't know if this has been reported or if the method to install VMWare tools has changed for Debian 9.X but I am having the classical issue of the fullscreen that is not working on Debian 9.X, even after the installation of either open vm tools or VMWare tools. My host OS is a Windows 7 and I am running on VMWare 14.X

After having installed my Debian 9.X with the default Debian environment, I have followed the process described here: http://partnerweb.vmware.com/GOSIG/Debian_9.html#Tools to install open VM tools. 
I have also retried using VMWare tools instead of open VM, both didn't work. I have tried with several interfaces (KDE, Cinnamon, Gnome) and none of them worked.

I have then installed Debian 8.X, and it is working perfectly, using open VM tools and following the exact same process.

Anyone had the same issue and solved it? Is there any tricks to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if this helps, but I managed to get full screen after manually running:

```
/usr/bin/vmware-user
```

That said, the whole installation of VMWare Tools doesn't seem to be seamless on Debian 9.